# depression and anxiety

Tags: discussion

In reference to this question, I'm not really into the close:

[Building muscle with depression and anxiety](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/39997/building-muscle-with-depression-and-anxiety)

There are [piles of questions asking how to exercise with injuries.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=with%20injury) I'll just be blunt: it's the **mental health stigma** aspect that's making this closed. Had they asked about lifting with a bad work sleep schedule or exercising with an injured hand, they would have gotten ideas. [Running with a cold got decent upvotes](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/248/should-you-run-with-a-cold).

Answer (score 1):

I'm open to discussing it of course.

I submit that the existence of open questions with the same patterns is not cause for keeping another one open though. Two wrongs don't make a right, as it were.

> There are piles of questions asking how to exercise with injuries.

Your 'with injury' search criteria doesn't really prove that. You're just finding posts that contain those two words in whatever order or location. In fact, looking it over, *most* examples seem to have nothing to do with existing injuries, but rather injury prevention, and the word "with" somewhere in the post, since it's a fairly common word in the English language.

Here's a snippet from the first page of results from your search query:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As we can see, this doesn't really prove that there are "piles of questions about how to exercise *with injury*".

If there are existing, open questions about how to train with injuries that can be made worse by receiving bad advice, I would be more inclined to close those, than to keep new ones open.

> I'll just be blunt: it's the mental health stigma aspect that's making this closed

Admittedly, I had to re-check the definition of the word "stigma" to see if I remembered it wrong. Do you really think I closed the question because I think mental health problems are disgraceful or to be ashamed of?

By my estimation, the asker is in need of professional help, because they're having trouble with even getting to the gym due to chronic mental fatigue. And as the `put on hold` message makes clear, "Questions on general health and medical advice are off-topic here; you should contact a qualified medical professional instead."

**In short**

For now, I stand by my decision to close that question, as I feel the asker needs help with more profound issues than the purely physical. But despite my long-winded response, I truly *am* open to further discussion. And should the majority disagree with me, I trust the majority.

Answer (score 1):

I will repost the question here as it has been deleted -

> If anyone knows anxiety, you'd know that it keeps you awake at night and if anyone knows depression, you'd know that it drains you of all your energy during the day. In other words, both combined is like an old cellphone. Takes forever to charge and just minutes for the battery to run out. How can one possibly build muscle being in such a state?

This could be an acceptable question, if it were rewritten. As it is currently, it (to me) asks more about the depression/anxiety than it does anything else, and as such I agree it was off topic. If it were worded so that the conditions were not the primary focus (i.e. how do you train around them, as in many of the questions that Alec linked), then it should be acceptable.

If treating the injury/condition is the primary focus, not really on topic. If the question is how to train around/in spite of/with the injury, on topic.